# cmakeable version of protocol buffers

Tags: cross-platform, cmake, protocol-buffers

StackOverflow community!

I want to embed protocol buffers into some project that supports cmake.
As I undrestood, google [doesn't provide this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list)

Any suggestions? Who tried to create cmakeable protocol buffers library?
Are there lots of not cross-platform places at the source or there is no at all.

Where can I take it if it exists?
What else cmakeable is there instead of protocol buffers?

Pls, don't ask me why I don't install protocol buffers, and just use compiled libraries,
I need to embed it inside the project.
If it is really bad idea, then, please, explain why.

Answer (score 4):

I created a set of CMakeLists.txt for protobufs for embedding into our build systems, and offered to contribute these to protobufs, but the people at Google weren't interested.

If you'd like, I can provide them "as-is". They work for 2.2.0, but you will probably have to do some hacking on your own to tweak them for your specific build system.

Comment: It would be great! Pls, send it to govordovsky@gmail.com

Comment: Throw them up on GitHub, I'd be interested in them as well.

Comment: I'm going to do that. I just want clearance from my employer, since the code was written on company time.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I've created a github repo for the code now: http://github.com/jesperes/protobuf-cmake